# How to create datetime value following the server time on vue/quasar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

*This topic translate from Bahasa Indonesia to English*

I apologize in advance, if this topic has been created but I can't find what I want, so I want to create a new topic.

I use the quasar date utility for validation on my application and it runs normally, but this becomes a problem when users change the date and time values on their computer, my application follows the date and time they set on their computer, and validation not work properly.

If in PHP I can handle it by following the date on the server, but what about quasar / vue js? I have also tried to use the Momentjs library but it is the same, maybe anyone can help solve a this problem that might this is a small problem?

```
//Create new datetime in timestamp format
let timeStamp = Date.now()
this.dateNow = date.formatDate(timeStamp, 'X')

//The value previously obtained from the user data
this.dateFromServer = __datetime value from user data on database in timestamp format__

//Validation
if(this.dateFromServer > this.dateNow){
   // You can access
}else{
  // Access Denied
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oke... I get an answer

I create a function to get accurate date, and I convert the value to timestamp, the user will no longer be able to manipulate the date :D But in console.log says: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. xD

```
createServerTime(){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', location.href, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    xhr.send('');

    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Date'))
}
```